# Which was the latest Matlab version that allowed to install MCR without Administrator rights?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I want compile some GUI into a Windows standalone application (`*.exe`). The main idea is run my applications in different computers WITHOUT the necessity of privileges to run it.

While doing [these steps](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/compiler/br2jauc-48.html), I noticed that when I want to run `vcredist_x86.exe` on a different computer administrator privileges are required. I asked in the official forum and they confirmed that is not possible.

There was also other interesting alternative with an older version here:
[How can I install the Matlab Component Runtime without Administrator rights when using MATLAB Compiler 4.6 (R2007a)](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4B6VFA/index.html?product=CO&solution=1-4B6VFA)

Despite the fact that now there is no supported way, **until which Matlab version was it possible run standalone apps without privileges?**

My version is 2010b but I can use the most recent version which support the possibility to run MCR without privileges. I have Matlab compiler but not Matlab code generator (to automatic translate into another language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab user executables require Microsoft DLLs to run.  No Matlab version is going to be able to run user executables without the required Microsoft DLLs.  One cannot install DLLs to Windows owned directories without admin privileges.  This is a configuration issue not a Matlab runtime issue.  Solution is to install the required DLLs to the **local** folder that has the user application in it.  Ignore all the stuff in the docs about "network redributables" and "registering" DLLs.

I don't know if it is possible to run `vcredist_x86.exe` without privileges. It may be a matter of setting the install path to your local directory instead of "Program_Files...".  Either way it doesn't matter as `vcredist_x86.exe` should not be necessary.

I don't know if what you trying to do is possible or if Matlab has blocked it somehow  but  I think you have gotten confused on how to get there and have compounded your problems by trying to install to non-user directories.